# Conditional color formatting of pandas data for export to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, colors, output-formatting

I have a pandas `dataFrame` containing classifier prediction output:

```
actual_label    predicted_label
1               1
1               2
```

(The first prediction is right and second prediction is wrong). I want to perform conditional formatting on these outputs using pandas. All correct predictions should be `green`, all wrong predictions should be `red` and output can be saved to excel. Is there any way to do it in pandas?

Comment: Do you want to do this color output in the terminal, in a Jupyter notebook, on a plot, in HTML/CSS...? "Formatting" tells us nothing.

Comment: It's mentioned at the end that it would be for output in excel :-)

Comment: No it only says "can be saved to excel" way down the bottom, and I only saw that now. You could easily have meant "display in console, save to excel" or "display in HTML/CSS, save to excel"